# WooCommerce: How to require State Dropdown box in ADMIN New Order section

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to require a handful of fields in the Admin area of WooCommerce inside of the Create New Order form. I have successfully worked out how to do this for all of the fields except for the State drop-down menus. Here is what I have so far (all of this code is functioning properly):

```
// Require certain fields in NEW ORDER creation via Admin
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'woocommerce_require_admin_billing_fields');
function woocommerce_require_admin_billing_fields( $fields ){
    $fields['first_name']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    $fields['last_name']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    $fields['address_1']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    $fields['city']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    $fields['postcode']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    $fields['country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' ); 
    $fields['email']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    $fields['phone']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields', 'woocommerce_require_admin_shipping_fields');
function woocommerce_require_admin_shipping_fields( $fields ){
    $fields['address_1']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    $fields['city']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    $fields['postcode']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    $fields['country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    $fields['state']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'required' => '1' );
    return $fields;
}
// Require fields that are not included in woocommerce_admin loops
function vic_require_admin_fields() {
     echo '<script>document.getElementById("excerpt").setAttribute("required", "1")</script>';              // order notes (excerpt)
     echo '<script>document.getElementById("_payment_method").setAttribute("required", "1")</script>';      // payment method
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'vic_require_admin_fields' );
```

I have tried to require the "State" drop-down field in a similar manner as the rest (through a filter targeting the "state" id) and I have also attempted to target it with a javascript action, but both efforts produced no solution. It looks like the way the form is constructed is through a boostrap drop-down? The actual  tag is set to display: none, so I can't really do much with that.

I can see that when I select a selection without a state, the SELECT field turns into an INPUT field, which is I think why I am unable to target it to add the required attribute:

[image]

It's alright if I can't do this with a filter. I'm thinking I may need some javascript attached to the button for form validation maybe? I couln't seem to find the actual form id, in order to validate through javascript, though I will probably look more around this evening when I'm home.

Any ideas to help me find a solution will be much appreciated!